# jQuery - DIV not to appear again after closing in whole site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have got this DIV, which is fully functional. It closes on click and doesn't load on next visit. Although it still shows on other sub-pages and I don't want it to. Closing should disable it for whole page and achieve to not reappear again, how can I seem to work this out?

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.recenzie_zatvaratko',function(){
$(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
      $(this).remove();
});
});
$(function(){  // jQuery(document).ready shorthand
$('.recenzie').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($.cookie('noShowWelcome')) $('.recenzie').hide();
else {
    $(".recenzie_zatvaratko").click(function() {
        $(".recenzie").fadeOut(1000);
        $.cookie('noShowWelcome', true);    
    });
}
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="recenzie">
<div class="recenzie_zatvaratko">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.atria.sk/db/wysiwyg/zatvorenie.png" /></div>
<a href="http://www.atria.sk/junkers-fw-120/" width="140"><img src="http://www.atria.sk/db/wysiwyg/fw120.png" /></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your js on the sub page and test whether it can read the cookie or not.

Comment: Does the cookie save to github.com since that's where the source is?  But when you try reading it in your script, you're reading from your own site?

Comment: JS is always the same, so the DIV window is! My JS is in the head section.

Comment: @MartinSzabo I am asking you to the check whether your js is able to read the cookie on the sub page. just test it and leave a comment about it. just try an alert message on the content of the cookie